# Como meio que colocar div atrás e conteudo em cima

Tags: html, css, div

Tipo assim alguém pode meio que me explicar como que funciona isto? tipo tem uma div atras onde fica a imagem, e em cima fica o conteudo do site em sí... 
   Video de como é: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cBmrM_sIZZU

Comment: Isto é um efeito de Css chamado parallax, pode ser visto em exemplos como este https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryhow_css_parallax_demo.htm

Comment: Valeu amigo! Eu não tinha conhecimento sobre isto.